# ¿Como reemplazar class="active" al dar clic?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una linea

```
@foreach($resultado['modelo'] as $resul)
  <li><a href="{{route('ficha-proyecto_modelo', ['id' => $resul->id,$resul->proyecto_id ])}}" class="active">{{$resul->nombre_modelo}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

y cada vez que pasas por el foreach el nombre queda tomado con una linea verde...

Lo que necesito es saber que clase puede reemplazar el active para que cuando yo cambie de nombre esa linea aparezca donde tengo la información

Comment: No se comprende bien qué es lo que necesitas, intenta ser un poco más específico con respecto al reemplazo de la clase active.

Comment: Por favor te invito a que leas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask